# Cassandra configs

Tags: cassandra

Recently I began to study Cassandra. Please help me understand what effect these settings (I need your interpretation, I read the file cassandra.yaml):

1. memtable_flush_writers
2. memtable_flush_queue_size
3. thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb
4. in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb
5. slised_buffer_size_in_kb
6. thrift_max_message_length_in_mb
7. binary_memtable_throughput_in_mb
8. column_index_size_in_kb

Comment: This gives more detail for some of these: www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/configuration/node_configuration

Comment: In this page same information with cassandra.yaml

Comment: Please tell me how I can to increase the recording speed in cassandra?

Answer (score 5):

I know it's very late to answer.But I am answering it as it might help someone else.

The **most of the parameters** you have mentioned above are related to the Cassandra write operation.

**memtable_flush_writers :** 
It Sets the number of memtable flush writer threads. These threads are blocked by disk I/O, and each one holds a memtable in memory while blocked. If your data directories are backed by SSD, increase this setting to the number of cores.

**memtable_flush_queue_size :**
The number of full memtables to allow pending flush (memtables waiting for a write thread). At a minimum, set to the maximum number of indexes created on a single table

**in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb :** Size limit for rows being compacted in memory. Larger rows spill to disk and use a slower two-pass compaction process. When this occurs, a message is logged specifying the row key. The recommended value is 5 to 10 percent of the available Java heap size.

**thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb :** Frame size (maximum field length) for Thrift. The frame is the row or part of the row that the application is inserting.

**thrift_max_message_length_in_mb:** The maximum length of a Thrift message in megabytes, including all fields and internal Thrift overhead (1 byte of overhead for each frame). Message length is usually used in conjunction with batches. A frame length greater than or equal to 24 accommodates a batch with four inserts, each of which is 24 bytes. The required message length is greater than or equal to 24+24+24+24+4 (number of frames).

You can find more details at [Datastax Cassandra documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__memtable_flush_writers)